# Placing Google Analytics code in a seperate file breaks analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics

I was trying to store the Google Analytics code in a single file that all scripts reference.  But my file seems to be breaking the analytics code, and none of the pages that use this file show up in my google analytics report anymore.

Here is what I did in the head section of the scripts:

```
<?php
include ('global.php');
include ('connect.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<?php
printGoogleAnalytics();
?>


<?php
printGoogleSiteVerification();
?>

</head>
```

Here is what the printGoogleAnalytics() looks like in global.php :

```
function printGoogleAnalytics()
{
    if($production === true)
    {
$str = <<<EOT
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-9425856-20']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

           (function() {
           var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;
           ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
           var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
           })();
        </script>


EOT;
    echo $str;
    }
}
```

Any idea what may be breaking things?  Is there any other code needed from me?  I use PHP for this.

Comment: How does the code end up on the rendered page itself?

Comment: @yahelc Here is an example of a problematic page: http://www.comehike.com/hiking.php

Comment: @yahelc You see, if you do a view-source there, it doesn't show the Google analytics snippet at all.

Comment: That seems to indicate that `$production` is not explicitly set to true. What happens if you do `<?php echo "<!--" . $production."-->";`? Or, simply try using `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: @yahelc trying your suggestion now....

Comment: @yahelc oh that totally worked! Thank you!  Now I'll start figuring out why the $production variable was problematic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Google Analytics code wasn't appearing in the source of the generated page, it means that that block isn't getting evaluated.

The likeliest suspect is `if($production===true)`. Using 3 equals signs means its a STRICT comparison. What's probably happening is you're not setting it precisely to true, but instead to something that's kind of truthy.

You could get around that by either fixing how `$production` gets set, or using `==`.

Comment: Thank you.  By the way, from the comments on the other answer, I was actually trying to understand what is wrong with my doctype and similar declarations.  This was a helpful discussion.  Could you explain to me what I should do instead of what I am doing now?

Comment: and also, setting it to == didn't work either.  I have to look into that further.

Comment: @Genadinik your DOCTYPE is fine. Basically, the page has a doctype declaration of an XHTML page, but the content-type its served with is still HTML. That's a good thing, since Internet Explorer can't load pages with an XHTML content type. If you DID serve your pages with the XHTML content type, you would need to wrap inline scripts with CDATA to prevent the page from breaking. TL;DR You can safely upgrade to the HTML5 Doctype, `<!DOCTYPE html>`, and everything will work just fine. (Or, you can stay with the current one and things will remain fine.)

Comment: @Genadinik how is `$production` being set?

Comment: (For a more detailed background on this doctype shenanigan, read this: http://diveintohtml5.org/past.html#timeline